# Node.js and mysql bulletin board search function questions

Tags: mysql, node.js

The bulletin board is being implemented using node.js and mysql. I'm going to implement a search function this time. This is how the search form appears in the home and finally appears as a search page after processing in the controller. However, the table should be the same as the database and search form string. If it's not accurate, it won't come out.

form

```
    form(action=routers.search, method="get")
        input(type="text" placeholder="searh", name="result")
        input(type="submit" value="searh")
```

controller

```
export const search = (req, res) => {
  try {
    let result_value = req.query.result;
    let sql =
      "SELECT id, folder, title, nicName, date_format(writeDate, '%Y/%m/%d %T') as writeDate FROM board  where title=? order by id desc ";
    dbConnection.query(sql, [result_value], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.dir(result);
        res.render("search", {
          homeName: "watchingame",
          pageName: "search",
          routers,
          result_value,
          result
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

view

```
extends layouts/layout
block content
    div
        h2 #{result_value}
    table
        each board in result
            tr
                td=board.id
                td
                    a(href=`/board${routers.boardDetail(board.id)}`)=board.title
                td=board.nicName
                td=board.writeDate
    a(href=`/board${routers.boardCreate}`) write
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
However, the table should be the same as the database and search form string. If it's not accurate, it won't come out.
```

I guess it means the result appears only if the title in query matches exactly with the title of the items inside the table.

If you want to do partial matching like `query=dog, matches=dogs, the dog, hotdog, etc...)`, then you should use `LiKE` and `%` operator.

Below is the example SQL statement.

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  folder, 
  title, 
  nicName, 
  date_format(writeDate, '%Y/%m/%d %T') as writeDate 
FROM board where title like %dog% order by id desc
```

Then it would try to find anything that has `dog` inside the title.

So your `sql` string should look something like

```
'SELECT 
  id, 
  folder, 
  title, 
  nicName, 
  date_format(writeDate, '%Y/%m/%d %T') as writeDate 
FROM board where title LIKE ' + connection.escape('%' + result_value + '%')
```

If you want to read more about the `SQL Like Operator` then checkout the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

Comment: 답변이 도움이 되었다면 제 답변 왼쪽 상단에 있는 체크 표시를 눌러서 답변을 승인(accept)할 수 있어요. 승인 부탁드립니다~ ([누군가 답변을 달았다면? - 스택오버플로우 가이드](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Comment: 오 이런게 있었는지 몰랐네요~ 승인체크 눌러습니다~ 감사합니다!